# Should I use Chocolate Bars to Enchant?

Tags: candy-box-2

Should I use chocolate bars to enchant, or save them?  If so, what are the best enchants?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely enchant your items. There's no really "best" enchantment. You'll trash most of them, eventually, except for the Knight Armor and the Spoon. You can get enough chocolate bars to get all the enchantments anyway.

Basically, for starters:
Red gloves: Shoot fireballs. They do 15 damage. Useful for taking down enemies from a distance. Unfortunately, they have no set direction.

Pink gloves: Give life regen. Useful for getting your health back (obviously).

Octopus crown with Jaspers: Shoot bigger fireballs in every direction. Once you have this, you'll trash the Red gloves.

Octopus crown with Obsidian: Summons an octopus, occasionally. They have a ton of health, and do a decent amount of damage. Their major flaw is that they will come towards you and **block your path** unless you have the pogo stick.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use them, you need to enchant your items.

All enchants are generally good. Some items can be enchanted multiple times if you get that item again (EG the gloves or octopus crown. Make sure you keep one Octopus crown unenchanted) You can only wear one at a time, though.